# Protect a .txt that holds a password

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, passwords

I'm creating a local adventure game using VS C++ that stores player information to the users local machine. Once the `.exe` is run, it sets up a folder hierarchy, and once a user is created, we write to these folders, and create some new ones. The users password is stored in a `.txt`, something like this:

```
c:\game\user_accounts\<username>\player_info\player_password.txt
```

The problem with this is of course the user can just open this `.txt` file and change it, which will change the password. I have already implemented an account password changing function which updates the file, so I don't want the user to be able to manually go into the `player_password.txt` file, or even be able to see what the password is.

My question is, once the `player_password.txt` file is created, how can I protect this file so that users cannot open it up and see what the password is?

Comment: Commonly, passwords are never stored in plain. Usually, we store the result of some [hash function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function).

Comment: This could maybe be done with the windows API, but storing only the salted hash is probably better & safer.

Comment: Rule of thumb: If your program can open a file on the user's computer, the user can also open it. Unless you have a server under your control that the program must communicate with, there is simply no way to prevent a user from controlling things happening on his PC (or doing all the things your program is doing).

Comment: A quick online search for how to store passwords: https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2013/11/20/serious-security-how-to-store-your-users-passwords-safely/

Comment: To add to others: why do you even need to store the password on the user's PC (in plain text no less)? Especially if the user has full control of it even without knowing the secret (by modifying this file).

Comment: Appreciating this feedback. Will have a look at the links above. Thank you all.

Comment: @DanM. I'm not aware of any other ways to store the password locally firstly. The game itself is just some local fun. I may store to a database at a later time but as of now it's all local, so just asking.

Comment: *Why* do you need a password at all here? Passwords are commonly used to authenticate entities, that are subsequently granted access to restricted resources. What resources do you need to protect when the entire application runs on the user's local machine?

Comment: Seems a little pointless to go to all this trouble for something that runs locally. You can save state to the local user profile and the system will do the rest. If you want to allow multiple users of your game who are all logged in to the same user account, then you don't need passwords at that point because these people already trust each other.

Comment: Thinking about this again, I think you're right. Also when a user creates an account, they're given a random unique ID, and they use their username and unique ID to update their player stats on the online leaderboard (this is the plan), but thinking about it now, I don't think I need a password really? Do I?